Why are output files written to different location?
In my Downloads directory, I have two directories: v1 and v2. 
Output of following script is placed in v1 instead of Downloads. 
Why?  I am running the script from the Downloads directory.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Full path to v1 
v1='/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Downloads/v1'

# Full path to v2 
v2='/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Downloads/v2'

# Loop through files in v1 and compare with v2
for file in "$v1"/*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    fileInv2=$(find "$v2" -type f -iname "$(basename "$file")")
    if [ -f "$fileInv2" ]; then
      sort "$file" "$fileInv2" | uniq -u > "${file}_Diff_Output.txt"
    fi
  fi
done

Q2) Is it possible to create a folder named ...../Downloads/output
and have the output files redirected to the output folder? 
The five dots means the leading path can be anything. 
Since I am running the script from the Downloads folder,
I want output files to go to ...../Downloads/output.

You redirect/create file with the variable file that is a full path from v1 directory + matching file(s).

Learn to use the shell debugging/trace setting. Add set -x near the top of the script. You will see each command as it is executed preceded with the + char (usually). In many cases  "strings" from your script will display as 'strings'. This is the shells way of "normalizing" it processing, it has converted all env vars to their values, run any sub-commands or command-substitutions. What you see preceded with + is exactly what the shell ran as a cmd. If you want to see what your code looks like before the vaiables etc are expanded, use set -vx.

The output file is being written into the v1 directory
because you specify the output as
> "${file}_Diff_Output.txt"

and ${file} is the full pathname to an input file that’s in v1
(from for file in "$v1"/*).
You can specify an output file in another directory
with a construct like
> "...../Downloads/output/$(basename "$file")_Diff_Output.txt"

You might want to assign $(basename "$file") to another variable,
for clarity and simplicity.

Running find for each file seems inefficient. I'd do something like:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# Full path to v1 
v1='/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Downloads/v1'

# Full path to v2 
v2='/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Downloads/v2'

diff_dir='/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Downloads/output'

typeset -A in_v1 in_v2

# record where each file with a given name (the `:t`ail of each path)
# is in each dir
for file ( $v1/**/*(ND.) ) in_v1[$file:t]=$file
for file ( $v2/**/*(ND.) ) in_v2[$file:t]=$file

# get the `k`eys of both associative arrays in two lists (a and b)
a=( ${(k)in_v1} ) b=( ${(k)in_v2} )

# Take the intersection of the two lists:
files_in_both=( ${a:*b} )

# Loop through files in v1 also found in v2
for file ($files_in_both)
  sort -- $in_v1[$file] $in_v2[$file] |
    uniq -u > $diff_dir/${file}_Diff_Output.txt

